# Format date according to locale, but without year in Android

Tags: android, string, date, xamarin.android, date-formatting

I want to format a day in such a way that the year is missing, and the month and the day are displayed as number, and all this should be according to the locale in Android (using Xamarin, but that shouldn't matter)

So far i have been using `Android.Text.Format.DateFormat.GetBestDateTimePattern`, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work properly with the pattern `ddMM`

With the following code

```
var formatString = Android.Text.Format.DateFormat.GetBestDateTimePattern(new Java.Util.Locale("de", "CH"), "ddMMyyyy");
formatString = Android.Text.Format.DateFormat.GetBestDateTimePattern(new Java.Util.Locale("de", "CH"), "ddMM");
formatString = Android.Text.Format.DateFormat.GetBestDateTimePattern(new Java.Util.Locale("fr", "CH"), "ddMMyyyy");
formatString = Android.Text.Format.DateFormat.GetBestDateTimePattern(new Java.Util.Locale("fr", "CH"), "ddMM");
```

I get these results:

```
dd.MM.yyyy
dd.MM.
dd.MM.yyyy
dd/MM
```

Unfortunately the last one is incorrect and has a discrepancy to the `ddMMyyyy` pattern returned for the same locale (btw it's the same behaviour for `fr FR`). What i want is `dd.MM.`

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think there is any discrepancy? Probably it's more common to use dd.MM.yyyy for dates with years and dd/MM for dates without year?

Comment: You could use C# Date formatting and use a custom format: `DateTime.Today.ToString("dd.MM.")`

Comment: @Divers well, there is a discrepancy, since one is formatted with dots and the other with slashes. The 2 native french speakers i have access to (one from Canada, the other from Switzerland) both said they'd write it with a dot.

Comment: @apineda That method ignores the locale, it would work for the french and the german case, but then it would also write the date with a dot in english, which isn't correct.

Comment: yeah but actually I meant "force" the format for those two specific locales (de and fr) and let the others use the built-in format.